# Formatting numbers in charts ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How do I format the data that is shown in the linechart of Charts? By default the data is shown as double, but I want it to be displayed as int.

```
let pre = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]
for i in 0..<pre.count {
    let preDataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: pre[i], xIndex: i)
    preEntries.append(preDataEntry)
}

let preChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: preEntries, label: "Pre")
lineChartView.data = lineChartData
```

[image]

Comment: Give integer values in your pre array if that does not work, you will need to change the format in your lineChartView class.

Comment: I tried but it says 'cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some formatter properties you could use:

`valueFormatter` in `ChartDataSet`

formatters in ChartYAxis:

```
/// the formatter used to customly format the y-labels
public var valueFormatter: NSNumberFormatter?

/// the formatter used to customly format the y-labels
internal var _defaultValueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
```

should be enough

Answer (score 9):

### **FIXED FOR SWIFT 3**

**YAxisValueFormatter.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Charts
class YAxisValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    let numFormatter: NumberFormatter

    override init() {
        numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        numFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

        // if number is less than 1 add 0 before decimal
        numFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1 // how many digits do want before decimal
        numFormatter.paddingPosition = .beforePrefix
        numFormatter.paddingCharacter = "0"
    }

    /// Called when a value from an axis is formatted before being drawn.
    ///
    /// For performance reasons, avoid excessive calculations and memory allocations inside this method.
    ///
    /// - returns: The customized label that is drawn on the axis.
    /// - parameter value:           the value that is currently being drawn
    /// - parameter axis:            the axis that the value belongs to
    ///

    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return numFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: value))!
    }
}
```

create `YAxisValueFormatter`class, and assign object to graph `leftAxis`

```
    // Number formatting of YAxis
    chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = YAxisValueFormatter()
```

Comment: How to do this for bar value?